# ViewWillAppear and ViewDidAppear dont fire ipad-mini

Tags: ios, swift, ipad-mini

In my app i present an admob interstitial add like this:

```
interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(view)
```

Where view is the current viewController

The interstitial add is shown on the entire screen and upon dismissal of this add the view controller ViewWillAppear and ViewDidAppear always get called beside on ipad-mini where those events are not fired for some reason

Any idea why?

Testing on real ipad-mini with OS 8.3

Devices which i tested: Iphone 5, 6, 4s

Comment: You mean Viewwillappar and didappear not called in iPhones and both methods are called in iPad mini? am i right?

Comment: The opposite on ipad mini those events are not fired

Comment: I have same task but i'm using different ad Network (iAd). and after dismissing interstitial ad there is called both the methods.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know AdMob specifically, but I've seen the behavior before. On an iPad, presenting a form sheet will not cause the parent view controller to disappear. So, no `-viewWillDisappear:`, `-viewDidDisappear:`, `-viewWillAppear:`, `-viewDidAppear:` cycle for the parent.

Depending on the implementation details of ad presentation, the parent view controller may still be appearing, only mostly covered by the ad. In that case, you are seeing the correct behavior.

Have you tried using the [`-interstitialDidDismissScreen:`](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/interstitial) callback instead of `-viewWillAppear`?

Comment: Using the ad callbacks was my first choice but the structure and optimization dont really allow it. The thing is that on the simulator the events are firing (Ipad2, retina,air etc...)